# PHP | Серверная консоль

Tags: php, linux, debian

Возможно-ли реализовать аналог серверной консоли Linux Debian на php с использованием exec, system и т.д.
Речь идёт не о выполнении одиночных команд, а полноценной консоли от имени www-data. С запоминание пути(cd), возможностью ввода инпутов и т.д.

Comment: А чем обычная консоль под www-data не подходит? Или запуск из-под него РНР скрипта?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Нужна именно консоль на PHP, без SSH и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример `execv()` на py + ws + js. Он не сложный - перепишите на php если нужно. Правда без асинхронщины сложно реализовать копирование в обе стороны - пробуй thread

https://github.com/alex-eri/jsterm/

запуск

```
python3 ./server.py /bin/bash
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

даже mc работает (только рамер подогнать `stty rows 36 cols 140`)